# How to handle URLs with dots in Next.js 14 App folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I need a URL structure for my detail page at work. Everything works fine, but if the URL contains any dots, it returns a 404 page. For example:

`mysite.com/product/xxxxx-yyyyyy-zzzzz-3.5kg-id`

Due to the dot in the URL (specifically, ‘3.5kg’), it results in a 404 error. I’ve tried using the [[…slug]] option and  structures, rewrites in Next config but they didn’t work.

Comment: You can use rewrites in Next.JS. Checkout this for more information https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, but still returns 404. Thank you.

Comment: Then, you may open an issue on their official GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

It was because of i18n configurations. I changed middleware matcher and excluded all dots. It works fine now.

Comment: Yes I had the same problem it was due to the default middleware matcher from the next-international library. Converting this: matcher: ["/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next|favicon.ico|robots.txt).*)"] to matcher: ["/((?!api|static|_next|favicon.ico|robots.txt)(?!.*\\/[^\\/]*\\.[^\\/]{2,4}$).*)"] solved it for me.